# Вытащить число из сообщения в телеграмме

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Всем привет. Хотел бы попросить помощи у вас с объяснением, как можно сделать мою задумку. Мне нужно вытащить из входящих сообщений число и, если число > 50, ответ такой. Если число < 50, ответ иной.

Пример:
bot: Количество: 76
me: Продать

bot: Количество: 11
me: Купить

Вопрос: как получить это число программно и сравнить его с другим числом?

моя попытка в код:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    text = event.text.split()
    if text[0] in event.raw_text == "Количество: ":

        if x >= 31:
            await event.respond('Продать')
        if x <= 31:
            await event.respond('Купить')
```

p.s. я слаб в программировании

Заранее спасибо всем, кто сможет помочь/объяснить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, что там сообщение всегда будет вида `Количество: число`, поэтому можно реализовать так

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    text = event.text.split()
    if text[0] in event.raw_text == "Количество: ":
        number = int(event.raw_text[12::])
        if number >= 31:
            await event.respond('Продать')
        elif number <= 31:
            await event.respond('Купить')
```

Comment: Да! работает. как нужно, спасибо тебе!

Comment: что делает строчка ``if text[0] in event.raw_text == "Количество: ":``?

Comment: @Эникейщик без понятия, я у автора вопроса код взял

Comment: @sxtrfly если ответ Вам помог, то пометьте его как правильный